# How do I do a WHERE LIKE query on multiple keywords in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with a where `like` query and I want the search field to return any field with 'gold or diamond of bronze'. A user types in what is gold in the search engine and it doesn't return any data. This is the query:

```
$sql = ("SELECT metals,  FROM metaltable WHERE search LIKE '%$usersearch%'");
```

Because the string contains 'what is gold', it doesn't return any data and if I type in gold, then it returns data, because it doesn't have the 'what is'

The table stucture is:

```
    ***metaltable***
 id      metals
1        gold
2        silver
3        bronze
4        diamond
```

I want the query to return any row with a keyword no matter how many characters the user enter in the search engine.

For example, if a user searches for what are the components of a diamond, I want the query to return row 4 because that keyword 'diamond' is in the search.

Comment: I think you want `WHERE metals LIKE '%$usersearch%'` rather than `WHERE search LIKE '%$usersearch%'`.

Comment: `SELECT metals,` < that trailing comma, is an instant syntax error.

Comment: You can explode your string to have an array of words. Then you can loop this array and append SQL query to match for these keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Keyword,b.metals 
FROM(
      SELECT 'usersearch' AS Keyword
      FROM metaltable  
    ) AS a 
INNER JOIN metaltable AS b
ON a.Keyword like '%'+b.metals+'%'
```

Put your user input to 'usersearch', it would be work.
When you input 'gold or diamond of bronze', it would show three records.